# I want to swap values of array b and not of array a . But values of array a is changing simultaneously too. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to swap values of array b and not of array a . But values of array a is changing simultaneously too.

```
   int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    int number = 0;
    int b[] = new int[n];
    queue m = new queue(n);
    while (j > i) {
        number = 0;
        b = a;
        int temp = b[n - i];
        b[n - i] = b[n - j];
        b[n - j] = temp;
      }
```

Comment: What do you think that the line `b = a;` does?

Comment: Besides that, you forgot to actually ask a question. Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to debug small programs (external link)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

In the  line 8, you are pointing reference of array b to reference of the array a by using "b=a". Since when you are changing array b automatically array a is getting changed.

Copy the array a into array b and then perform the same operation. Refer the snippet below -

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
int number = 0;
int b[] = new int[n];
queue m = new queue(n);
while (j > i) {
    number = 0;
    System.arraycopy( a, 0, b, 0, a.length );
    int temp = b[n - i];
    b[n - i] = b[n - j];
    b[n - j] = temp;
  }
```